# Stereoscopic 3D view in OpenGL 2.0

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, stereoscopy

I have been hunting around everywhere for an example, demo code or tutorial of a side by side (Stereoscopic) OpenGl example for Android.  I believe it require the use of gl_Scissor, with the explosion of new VR smart phone devices (vRase, OpenDive) I would of thought there would be some help for Android.

Comment: If you use ndk with c++ or c It doesn't matter platforms IOS ANDROID. And you can the file here http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596804831/readme.html#WireframeSkeleton

Comment: But it is for IOS as I mentioned it can be used for also android if you use ndk